# MYSQL & PHP: mysql ignoring first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have never had this happen before. The query is very simple by the way.

```
$q  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");  
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {  
    echo $r['fieldname'];  
}
```

edit: the first <strike>column</strike> (row) is skipped. but when I deleted the first column, the second one was ignored.

**(SOLVED)**

I figured it out. I declared mysql_fetch_array **twice**.

```
$q  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");    
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q) //over here 


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {  
        echo $r['fieldname'];  
}
```

I have to be more careful, but thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'the first column is skipped'?

Comment: `fieldname` is your column name. So how can it *ignore* the that column?

Comment: is the field NULL/empty, so you may not see anythind echoed by any chance? If not you probably get a WARNING error, correct?

Comment: @Miroslav Solanka, the null field is set "NO"

Comment: @danyentezari Please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use full list of columns in your select statement. Code you have posted is an example of bad programming. Do it this way

```
$q  = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname FROM $TABLE");  
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {  
    echo $r['fieldname'];  
}
```

Comment: This should really be a comment since you don't answer the question. +1 though because it is good advice.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Every thing seems okey, but it worth trying with **MYSQL_ASSOC**

```
$q  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");  
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
    echo $r['fieldname'];  
}
```

Comment: Why not using mysql_fetch_assoc() then? mysql_fetch_array returns as BOTH numeric and associative array.

Comment: thats right , i was trying to working of question, instead i could suggested to use some standard class for these jobs.